# include Spring Boot Rest Api Jar file into Another Spring project

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have Spring boot Rest api , which works fine

```
@RequestMapping("/api/get")
public PomData getPomData( ) throws IOException {

    PomData pd=new PomData();
    pd.setName("name");
    pd.setVersion("version");

    return pd;

}
```

I want to call this

```
getPomData() (@RequestMapping 'api/get')
```

via URL, From Another project.

I've added this to that another project's POM file

```
<dependency>
<groupId>RestApi</groupId>
<artifactId>RestApi</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/RestApi.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

ANd i'm trying to  send request to  url    using ajax like this

```
$.ajax({url: "/api/get",success: function(result){
      alert();
    }});
```

but 404 PAGE NOT FOUND
what To do?

Comment: Are you trying to develop some kind of microservice based architecture? Then, you should consider launching the two services separately, and not include one into another as a dependency.

Comment: thank you for answer.
i'm making some own libraries. exactly, that method must return Project's POM.xml info From which I'll call it.

Comment: Your problem probably is spring-boot isn't searching in the right place. A `@SpringBootApplication` searches by default in the package its declared in and its sub-packages. So if your `@SpringBootApplication` is in `com.tsotne.myapp` but your api is in `com.tsotne.myapi`, it won't find the `@RequestMapping` because it's not in `com.tsotne.myapp`. If you add `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.tsotne.myapi")`, it should find it.

Comment: thank you mnewton,
 it works.